# android camerax image analyzer preview lag

Tags: android, performance, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to use an image analyzer, but I am not performing any operation on the image, yet I face with terrible lag on the preview

```
 val analyzerDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
        val myAnalyzer = MyAnalyzer()

        // Create an instance of ImageAnalysis
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()


        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(analyzerDispatcher.executor, myAnalyzer)

class MyAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    val TAG:String = MyAnalyzer::class.java.simpleName
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        val elapsedAnalysisTime = measureTimeMillis {
            Log.i(TAG,"${image.format}")
            image.close()
        }
        image.use {
            if (elapsedAnalysisTime < 1000) {
                Thread.sleep(1000 - elapsedAnalysisTime)
                //return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to what is going wrong, I tried on Emulator(Pixel 5 API 29) and a similar device, and both have the same issue.

Comment: Just for info tried to execute in the main thread as well, also tried to reduce the analyzer frame rate with no improvement

Comment: Your code looks right. I wonder if it has something to do with the `image.use` block. What if you remove it? Otherwise, if you can upload a minimal reproducible to GitHub, I can take a look.